# Rescaling the axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
########
# Plot #
########

fig = plt.figure(figsize = (8,8))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1) 

ax.set_xlabel('PC 1', fontsize = 15)
ax.set_ylabel('PC 2', fontsize = 15)
ax.set_title('2 Component PCA', fontsize = 20)

targets = [1, 0, -1]
colors = ['r', 'g', 'b']
for target, color in zip(targets,colors):
    indicesToKeep = finalDf['Label_Capture_Spread'] == target
    ax.scatter(finalDf.loc[indicesToKeep, 'PC 1']
               , finalDf.loc[indicesToKeep, 'PC 2']
               , c = color
               , s = 20)
ax.legend(targets)
ax.grid()
```

That plot has the axis way too extended. Is there a way to modify that code to scale the axis between -10 and 10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functions you are looking for are called `xlim` and `ylim`.

```
ax.set_xlim([-10, 10])
ax.set_ylim([-10, 10])
```